# i need to remove this text over flow in flutter. how can i do that?

Tags: flutter, text, overflow

I am facing error in the `Text` widget which is in `Column`.

```
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.songModel.displayNameWOExt,  <------- here is my text
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.songModel.artist.toString(),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                ),
              ],
            ),  
      ],
    ),   ), );
```

[This is what happened to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gipjR.jpg)

[This is what i need look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzgf2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the text with the container and give a specific size to the container after that use **overflow: TextOverflow.fade** or any other property of "overflow", because these properties only work when you give a size to textfield but you cant give size to textfield so wrap it with container.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Text` that is inside a `Row` widget with an `Expanded` widget:

```
Expanded(child: Text(/* Here the text*/),
```

Comment: my test is in a row, which is having another row inside it .
if i put the text inside the expanded widget then the expanded widget push the row. 
Putting the text inside a sized box with defined width helped me not pushing the row.

Answer (score 0):

try embedding the Text() widget inside a Expanded() widget [expanded documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Expanded is a  widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.